# Google App Engine unable to resolve www.facebook.com

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dns

## HACKY SOLUTION

So I spent quite some time figuring out exactly WHY this went wrong, turns out I wasn't wrong at all. Google was. What ended up being the case, was that there's a bug in the development SDK for the App Engine.

To solve this (rediciously annoying) issue, you can do the following:

Open the file called `/appengine/tools/devappserver2/python/sandbox.py`.

Add an import statement at the top of the file:

```
import socket as socket_original
```

Then replace this:

```
def load_module(self, fullname):
    if fullname in sys.modules:
      return sys.modules[fullname]
    return self.import_stub_module(fullname)
```

With this:

```
def load_module(self, fullname):
    if fullname == "socket":
      return socket_original
    if fullname in sys.modules:
      return sys.modules[fullname]
    return self.import_stub_module(fullname)
```

And boom, you're now using the original sockets library.

---

## ORIGINAL QUESTION

I'm using Google App Engine to host my web api, I currently need to make some API calls to certain websites (including facebook), making calls to any other website works just fine, but when the Google App Engine tries to resolve `www.facebook.com` I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: error('illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton',)
```

Example code:

```
# Fetching `www.google.com`
socket.gethostbyname_ex("www.google.com")    

# Returns:
[
    "www.google.com",
    [], 
    [
        "173.194.65.106",
        "173.194.65.104",
        "173.194.65.105",
        "173.194.65.103",
        "173.194.65.99",  
        "173.194.65.147"
    ]
]

# Fetching `www.twitter.com`
socket.gethostbyname_ex("www.twitter.com") 

# Returns:
[
    "twitter.com",
    [
        "www.twitter.com"
    ],
    [
        "199.16.156.230",
        "199.16.156.198",
        "199.16.156.102",
        "199.16.156.70"
    ]
]

# Fetching `www.facebook.com`
socket.gethostbyname_ex("www.facebook.com")

# Raises:
RuntimeError: error('illegal IP address string passed to inet_pton',)
```

Comment: you should add the solution as an answer to the question, not as a question update, to prevent the question from showing as unanswered...

Answer (score 0):

GAE supports sockets, but with some significant [Limitations and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions).

The SDK is mimicking these limitations and restrictions, so tweaking it to use the real socket library instead of the supplied one in your local development environment might not be such a great idea - your app might not actually work when deployed on GAE.

Comment: I see. As long as you're aware of the risk and OK with it you should be fine. I see you already filed an issue for it: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=13215. Thanks.